# Grafana pod crashloopbackoff after updating domain and port

Tags: kubernetes, oauth, openshift, keycloak, grafana

Im integrating keycloak OAuth login to Grafana in Openshift.

```
Keycloak Image Version - quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:15.0.2
Grafana Image Version - grafana/grafana:7.1.5
Kubernetes Version -  v1.21
Openshift Version - 4.8
```

The keyclaok is exposed at Route: `http://keycloak-keycloak.router.default.svc.cluster.local.167.254.203.104.nip.io`
The Grafana is exposed at Route: `https://grafana.router.default.svc.cluster.local.167.254.203.104.nip.io`
The keycloak is created with Realm - `devops` and client - `grafana` and these values are added to Grafana deployment as Environmental variable as follows

```
GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_NAME=OAuth
GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_ENABLED=true
GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_ALLOW_SIGN_UP=true
GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID=grafana
GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET=33341c00-daf2-4170-a66f-c2c7c23ad151 
GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_AUTH_URL=http://keycloak-keycloak.router.default.svc.cluster.local.167.254.203.104.nip.io/auth/realms/devops/protocol/openid-connect/auth
GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_TOKEN_URL=http://keycloak-keycloak.router.default.svc.cluster.local.167.254.203.104.nip.io/auth/realms/devops/protocol/openid-connect/token
GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_API_URL=http://keycloak-keycloak.router.default.svc.cluster.local.167.254.203.104.nip.io/auth/realms/devops/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_TLS_SKIP_VERIFY_INSECURE=true
```

With this when I browse the Grafana route and click on `Sign in with OAuth` I get error in screen - `Inavalid Prameter Redirect URI`. In the keycloak logs i see error -  `error=invalid_redirect_uri, redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/login/generic_oauth`.
Its taking `localhost:3000` as Redirect URI, but i have specified the right redirect URI in client section of keycloak web i.e, : `https://grafana.router.default.svc.cluster.local.167.254.203.104.nip.io/*`.

While debugging this issue came across a similar issue : https://github.com/cetic/helm-fadi/issues/39.
Hence I have added these two environmental variables to Grafana:

```
GF_SERVER_DOMAIN=grafana.router.default.svc.cluster.local.167.254.203.104.nip.io
GF_SERVER_HTTP_PORT=80
```

This has resulted in pod crashloopbackoff with following error in logs:

```
t=2021-12-31T11:29:26+0000 lvl=info msg="HTTP Server Listen" logger=http.server address=[::]:80 protocol=https subUrl=//grafana.router.default.svc.cluster.local.167.254.203.104.nip.io:80 socket=
t=2021-12-31T11:32:53+0000 lvl=info msg="Shutdown started" logger=server reason="System signal: terminated"
t=2021-12-31T11:32:53+0000 lvl=info msg="Stopped Stream Manager"
```

Please help me to proceed.

Comment: BTW: Keycloak 15.0.2 is vulnerable https://www.keycloak.org/2021/12/cve.html. Grafana uses default scope `user:email`, which doesn't exist in the Keycloak by default, so it will be good idea also to define scopes in the Grafana Oauth config explicitly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped me in a great way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the [Grafana documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/generic-oauth/):

> You may have to set the root_url option of [server] for the callback URL to be correct.

So remove `GF_SERVER_DOMAIN,GF_SERVER_HTTP_PORT` and configure `GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL` properly (I guess correct value for your setup is `https://grafana.router.default.svc.cluster.local.167.254.203.104.nip.io`)

Grafana will be able to generate correct redirect URL with this setup.